# Mixing QNA maker bot with hard coded responses

Tags: node.js, botframework, chatbot

I am trying to make a bot that has a hard coded welcome and then goes into a dialog with QNA maker. The code I have below does not work. It ends up sending the case 'Vraagen' to QNA maker instead of waiting for a user response. I would also like to have a hard coded dialog like 'Please ask your question:" with QNA maker dialog but I have not found how to make it. Thanks in advance.

```
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);

bot.dialog('/', [
    function(session){
        session.beginDialog('welcome');
    }
]);

bot.dialog('welcome',
    [
        function (session) {
        builder.Prompts.choice(session, 
                            'Hallo, Ik ben de citybot, U kunt mij vragen stellen of contactgegevens ontvangen. Om het gesprek op elk moment opnieuw te starten, zeg alsjeblieft stop.',
                            'Vraagen|Contact Info',
                            {listStyle: builder.ListStyle.button});
        },
        function (session, results){
            var selection = results.response.entity;
            switch(selection){
                case "Vraagen":
                    return session.beginDialog('qna');
                case "Contact Info":
                    return session.beginDialog('contact');
            }
        }
    ]
);

bot.dialog('restart-welcome',
[
    function (session) {
    builder.Prompts.choice(session, 
                        'Is er nog iets waarmee ik je kan helpen?',
                        'Vraagen|Contact Info',
                        {listStyle: builder.ListStyle.button});
    },
    function (session, results){
        var selection = results.response.entity;
        switch(selection){
            case "Vraagen":
                return basicQnAMakerDialog.beginDialog;
            case "Contact Info":
                return session.beginDialog('contact');
        }
    }
]
).triggerAction({
    matches: /^stop$/i,
});;

//=========================================================
// Recognizers
//=========================================================

var qnarecognizer = new builder_cognitiveservice.QnAMakerRecognizer({
    knowledgeBaseId: 'XXXX', 
    subscriptionKey: 'XXXX',
    top: 4});

    var basicQnAMakerDialog = new builder_cognitiveservice.QnAMakerDialog({
        recognizers: [qnarecognizer],
        defaultMessage: 'No match! Try changing the query terms!',
        qnaThreshold: 0.3
    });

bot.dialog('qna', basicQnAMakerDialog);

basicQnAMakerDialog.beginDialog
```

Comment: In your `switch` statement 1) Don't return the functions, just call them normally, and 2) add `break;` to the end of each `case` statement.

Comment: Also, you can add a "welcome message", that is a proactive message sent to the user when they first connect to the bot, using this code: https://gist.github.com/nwhitmont/d9910fcf7ab4048ee37bd5c789cfc375

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment! I tried removing the returns and implementing the breaks and I get the same errors!

Comment: I've had a similar question and solved it [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46019425/bot-framework-have-both-qna-maker-and-intentdialogs).