# Bot Framework: Have both QnA Maker and IntentDialogs

Tags: node.js, botframework

Is it possible to have both `QnAMakerDialog` and custom `IntentDialog` to work together? So, the QnA Maker will answer all FAQ related queries from the knowledge base and I can also hardcode some custom commands into the BotFramework.

Something like:

```
var basicQnAMakerDialog = new cognitiveservices.QnAMakerDialog({
    recognizers: [recognizer],
    defaultMessage: 'Sorry, I did not understand that.',
    qnaThreshold: 0.3
});

bot.dialog('/', basicQnAMakerDialog);

bot.dialog( new builder.IntentDialog()
.matchesAny([/Test/i], [
        function (session) {
           session.send('This is not from QnA Maker');
        }
])
);
```

My current output when I type 'Test' is the `defaultMessage` from QnA maker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. This code gave me the desired output:

```
var qnarecognizer = new cognitiveservices.QnAMakerRecognizer({
    knowledgeBaseId: '', 
    subscriptionKey: '',
    top:4});

var intentrecognizer = new builder.IntentDialog();

var intents = new builder.IntentDialog({ recognizers: [intentrecognizer, qnarecognizer] });
bot.dialog('/', intents);

intents.matches('qna', [
    function (session, args, next) {
        var answerEntity = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(args.entities, 'answer');
        session.send(answerEntity.entity);
    }
]);

intents.matchesAny([/Test/i], [
        function (session) {
           session.send('This is not from QnA Maker.');
        }
]);

intents.onDefault( [
        function (session) {
           session.send('Sorry, I don\'t know that.');
        }
]);
```